# Dynamic Array that sumproduct with filters (CHOOSE + SUMPRODUCT)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date column and two other columns. I want to make a dynamic array function that shows the months and the sumproduct of the other two columns for each month and also filter by the year in the cell D2.

My current formula is this `=CHOOSE({1,2}, SORT(UNIQUE(TEXT(B5:B14,"MMMM"))), SUMPRODUCT(C5:C14,D5:D14,--(YEAR(B5:B14)=D2)))`

It filter by year but I dont have any idea of how to sumproduct by the month in the dynamic array.

I know that it will easy add another column and multiply the two columns but this is for a real task with a file of more than 200K rows, so add another row is not an option.
(**click on Image of Worksheet configuration to see the example of the dynamic arrray**)

[Image of Worksheet configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEtVz.png)

Sample Data Table:

| Date | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-15 | 19 | 23 |
| 2021-01-15 | 12 | 15 |
| 2021-01-30 | 16 | 22 |
| 2021-02-15 | 13 | 11 |
| 2021-02-28 | 29 | 12 |
| 2021-02-28 | 15 | 14 |
| 2021-03-03 | 14 | 15 |
| 2021-03-03 | 25 | 27 |
| 2021-03-03 | 16 | 21 |
| 2021-03-03 | 29 | 27 |
| 2020-01-15 | 10 | 23 |
| 2020-01-20 | 18 | 30 |
| 2020-01-30 | 27 | 11 |
| 2020-02-15 | 22 | 18 |
| 2020-02-28 | 23 | 11 |
| 2020-02-28 | 22 | 18 |
| 2020-03-03 | 29 | 17 |
| 2020-03-03 | 20 | 17 |
| 2020-03-03 | 13 | 13 |
| 2020-03-03 | 19 | 22 |

Comment: I see that you are using the `UNIQUE` function; does your version of Excel also have access to the `FILTER` function?

Comment: This would be so much easier if you would put the data in a form we can copy paste instead of recreating by hand.

Comment: BTW you will want to do two SUMIFS() that are multiplied together.

Comment: @Chronocidal Yes, I have access to all dynamic array functions, also to Let and some other new functions.

Comment: @ScottCraner sorry but I dont your idea of put the data in a form, can you explain it more?

Comment: @ScottCraner Unfortunately, (2*3)+(4*5)=26, which is not the same as (2+4)*(3+5)=48

Comment: @Chronocidal but sumifs will return an array where sumproduct will not.

Comment: @ScottCraner I had assumed that Luis wanted cell H5 to be SumProduct for January 2021, so (19*23)+(12*15)+(16*22)=969 as a single value, rather than an array — although, I may just be misreading the question

Comment: @Chronocidal no, I agree with you on this.  As I can see it, it cannot be done with a single dynamic formula.  It will need to have the first do the month and then the do the second column separately because it would need to be dragged/copied down.  Unless the user is willing to use a helper column.

Comment: @Chronocidal yep, you are right. I want the result for January 2021 wich is 969 and the same operation for each month in my range (February and march in this case).

Comment: @LuisPulido I have spent a lot of time on this.  I do not see anyway to satisfy both your requirements, dynamically spillable and no helper column.  If that is a must then you will need to create your own udf in vba.  There just is no way that I know of to do what you ask with just formula.  You have examples below of both methods, one that uses a helper and another that needs to be copied down a fixed number of times.

Comment: @LuisPulido I have added a hybrid formula-udf version below.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a helper column:

[image]

Then we can use SUMIFS:

```
=LET(
      dt,     B5:B24,
      ttl,    E5:E24,
      tgt,   D2,
      mnt,    SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(MONTH(dt),YEAR(dt)=tgt))),
      omnt,   UNIQUE(TEXT(SORT(FILTER(dt,YEAR(dt)=tgt)),"MMMM")),
      smttl,   SUMIFS(ttl,dt,">="&DATE(tgt,mnt,1),dt,"<"&DATE(tgt,mnt+1,1)),
      CHOOSE({1,2},omnt,smttl))
```

[image]

---

To do it without a helper column AND make it dynamic spillable we can use VBA and create a UDF that will do that:

```
Function SUMPRODUCTARRAY(dtrng As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, yr As Long, mnth As Variant) As Variant()
    Dim tempArr() As Variant
    ReDim tempArr(LBound(mnth, 1) To UBound(mnth, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    Dim dtrngA() As Variant
    dtrngA = dtrng.Value
    
    Dim rng1A() As Variant
    rng1A = rng1.Value
    
    Dim rng2A() As Variant
    rng2A = rng2.Value
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(mnth, 1) To UBound(mnth, 1)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = LBound(dtrngA, 1) To UBound(dtrngA, 1)
            If month(dtrngA(j, 1)) = mnth(i, 1) And Year(dtrngA(j, 1)) = yr Then
                tempArr(i, 1) = tempArr(i, 1) + (rng1A(j, 1) * rng2A(j, 1))
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    SUMPRODUCTARRAY = tempArr
    

End Function
```

Then the formula is:

```
=LET(
      dt,     B5:B24,
      fst,    C5:C24,
     scd,    D5:D24,
      tgt,   D2,
      mnt,    SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(MONTH(dt),YEAR(dt)=tgt))),
      omnt,   UNIQUE(TEXT(SORT(FILTER(dt,YEAR(dt)=tgt)),"MMMM")),
      smttl,   SUMPRODUCTARRAY(dt,fst,scd,tgt,mnt),
      CHOOSE({1,2},omnt,smttl))
```

[image]

Comment: @ciso This was written prior to many of the new formulas.  SUM with FILTER probably will do it.  I do not have time right now to do some testing.  Why not write up a follow up question on this one.  with what you tried to do it.

Comment: I've tried many things so far, no luck.  The OP is the right question and a follow-up question would be a duplicate.  I will post an answer if I find one.  Goal is no helper column, no VBA, and spillable.  Filter sounds like a good idea to try, will see.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    FILTER($C$5:$C$24,
        TEXT($B$5:$B$24,"mmmmyyyy") = $G5&$D$2),
    FILTER($D$5:$D$24,
        TEXT($B$5:$B$24,"mmmmyyyy") = $G5&$D$2))
```

This uses the `FILTER` function to produce 2 arrays of data, where the Month and Year match the values specified (one for each column of data).  It then `SUMPRODUCT`s those arrays together.

Unfortunately, I was not quite able to make it work with just 1 `FILTER`, but someone else might be able to figure out if that is possible.

(N.B. Because of the use of `TEXT` to convert the date to a string, this might have issues if Excel is not set to the same language that you wrote the month in; for example, if Excel is set to English, then it will not recognise the Spanish months shown in your example.)

Comment: `SUM(FILTER($C$5:$C$24*$D$5:$D$24,TEXT($B$5:$B$24,"mmmmyyyy") = $G5&$D$2))` works for me.  but that can not be made "Spillable". it would need to be copied/dragged down.

Comment: I just cannot see a way to satisfy both requirements, no helper column and spillable.